# WPF disable tooltips in child elements

Tags: wpf, grid, visibility, tooltip

Please help me - how can I disable tooltips on child elements in Grid?

```
<Grid x:Name="root">
    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="0,0,52,0">

        <Popup Placement="Bottom">
               <StateButton x:Name="FullScreenButton"
                                    Command="{Binding Path=FullScreenCommand}"
                                    wpfutil:CustomToolTipService.Content="Exit full screen (Esc)"
                                    ToolTip="{CustomToolTipExtension}"/>
        </Popup>
    </Border>

    <Border     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom">

        <Popup Placement="Bottom">
                <Border x:Name="OverlayControlHolder"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
        </Popup>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

I need to bind IsEnabled tooltip property on the Main Grid.
How can I reach it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{..}"

Comment: I may misunderstood you,
ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=(ToolTipService.IsEnabled)}"